# Tidying up javascript with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

I know this code is messy:

```
$("#tog-desc").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(".description").slideToggle();

    if( $(this).hasClass("open") ) {
        $(this).html("Hide Description").css("background-position", "85px 3px");
    }
    else {
        $(this).html("Show Description").css("background-position", "88px -10px");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But I'm not sure how this could be tidied up with the ternary operator to make it neat and concise. I always seem to end up writing overly long if/else statements with Javascript and I'd like to understand how not to have to do so!

Edit: by default #tog-desc shows "Show Description" and .description is hidden, in case this wasn't obvious

Thanks.

Comment: Well it looks like you got some distinct suggestions to choose from :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#tog-desc").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), has_cls = $this.hasClass("open");
    $this.toggleClass("open")
       .text((has_cls ? "Hide" : "Show") + " Description")
       .css("background-position", has_cls ? "85px 3px" : "88px -10px");

    $(".description").slideToggle()

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Or make the background-position part of the `.open` css class...

```
$("#tog-desc").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("open")
       .text(($this.hasClass("open") ? "Hide" : "Show") + " Description");

    $(".description").slideToggle();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This is the most concise so I shall declare it the winner! Although in all fairness I do struggle (as a designer but self-taught coder) to actually understand this and as Chris says above, perhaps that's just as important. Thanks a lot though

Comment: @Alexander: Fair point. I updated with that improvement, and also changed `html()` to `text()`.

Comment: @artparks: That's definitely a consideration. Another possibility is to have two distinct elements, and show/hide them instead of modifying a single element. That may be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

As you've seen in some of the other answers here, it is certainly possible to shorten your code by a few lines using ternary operators.

However, I question the value of doing so. Code is not a contest to write the shortest form possible. Performance-wise, there is absolutely **nothing** wrong with your code; there is nothing more or less inherently performant about a ternary compared to an if statement.

Further, one must take in to consideration maintainability. Your code, as it stands, is more scannable and understandable in its current form. While a ternary operator may save you a few lines, again, it isn't about the lines, it is about delivering functionality with reasonable performance. The places you should be evaluating for improvement is not code length per se, but rather code reuse, efficiency, and finally file size by way of a minifier.

There are times and places to use ternary operators -- it is not something you should sprinkle in already-working code just to eliminate a few clear-to-read, functional lines of code.

**More Reading**

- http://blog.ashodnakashian.com/2011/03/code-readability/
- https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zHb855D5fQAKix47YCeVCH6QUQFzwCTxuz5GFMoNQyc/edit?pli=1#slide=id.p
- The Art of Readable Code has a section on ternary - [http://www.amazon.com/The-Readable-Code-Dustin-Boswell/dp/0596802293](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596802293)

**EDIT** One thing... you *could* remove unnecessary curly braces around one-line conditionals:

```
$("#tog-desc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(".description").slideToggle();
    if( $(this).hasClass("open") )
        $(this).html("Hide Description").css("background-position", "85px 3px");
    else
        $(this).html("Show Description").css("background-position", "88px -10px");
});
```

Comment: You lost me in the "remove unnecessary curly braces" part. I can't agreed there

Comment: If this is final code, and the conditional is only one line, you *could* (emphasis important) remove those extra curly braces. I personally always leave them -- every time I take them off, I come back later and need to add something and curse myself for not having put them there (or for having taken them off)

Comment: Interesting points, thanks very much. I guess I just need to be less obsessive about such things... all the really concise answers below I struggle to understand.

Comment: +1 I think these are good points. And I especially like the "remove unnecessary curly braces" part. Get rid of the semicolons, and it reflects my own non-StackOverflow code. Nice and clean.

Comment: @artparks And **that** is just what I'm getting at. Great, you've constructed a super-awesome one-liner ternary-quantum-modulo operation that runs your entire application in 16 characters. You also have to sit there and read it for a few moments to parse just what in the hell it does. While you're distracted, someone lets your cat out and there's change missing off the dresser. Avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
var open = $(this).hasClass('open');
$(this)
  .html( ( open ? "Show" : "Hide" ) + " Description")
  .css("background-position", open ? '85px 3px' : '88px -10px' );
```

Is that what you're after? Basically:

```
<condition> ? <true_result> : <false_result>
```

Comment: You still need to toggle the class :)

Comment: @Alexander: I snipped only the `if...else...` portion of the code snippet (assuming that was the only portion needed refactoring). I didn't `slideToggle` or `e.preventDefault` either for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if it makes it *better*, but you could do something like this:

```
var update = $(this).hasClass('open') ? 
  { label: "Hide Description", position: "85px 3px" } :
  { label: "Show Description", position: "88px -10px" };

$(this).html(update.label).css("background-position", update.position);
```

Comment: Same, you still need to toggle the class :)

Comment: @Alexander ah yes you're right.  Anyway I like the answer that suggests doing this all with CSS (including the messaging, which could be kept in separate `<span>` elements) based on the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is any cleaner, but this should work:

```
$("#tog-desc").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(".description").slideToggle();

    var open = $(this).hasClass("open");
    $(this).html((open ? "Hide" : "Show") + " Description")
           .css("background-position", "85px " + (open ? "85px" : "3px");

    e.preventDefault();
});
```